# SuiteCrm Autoincrement Custom ID Field

Tags: suitecrm

Is there someone who can provide me some code and instruction to create an autoincrement Id Field in SUiteCrm?

Thanks,

Nico

Comment: Kindly elaborate more and show what you achieved till yet.

Comment: you need to create your own field type

Answer (score 0):

To be able to achieve this, you will have to create a new file in the given location with autoincrement.php as its name. 
 
custom/Extension/modules/module_name/Ext/Vardefs e.g. autoincrement.php with the following code:

```
<?php
     $dictionary['MODULE_NAME']['fields']['NAME_OF_FIELD'] =  array(
            'name' => 'NAME_OF_FIELD',
            'vname' => 'LBL_LABEL_NAME_OF_FIELD',
            'type' => 'int',
            'readonly' => true,
            'len' => 11,
            'auto_increment' => true,
           'disable_num_format' => true,
        );
?>
```

and also add unique index for the field in that file

```
<?php
     $dictionary['YOUR_MODULE']['indices']['NAME_FOR_INDEX'] = array(
            'name' => 'NAME_FOR_INDEX',
            'type' => 'unique',
            'fields' => array('NAME_OF_FIELD'),
     );
?>
```

Run a Quick Repair and Rebuild, in Admin -> Repair and execute the changes.

Thanks,